# Expression of the probability of a single point.

Tags: probability-theory

In my notes I have that the probability of a single point is

$P(X=a)=P(\{a\})$=$$\lim_{\epsilon \to \ 0^+}P(a- \epsilon<X\leq a)=$$

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to \ 0^+}(F_X(a)-F_X(a- \epsilon))=$$

\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } F_X \:is\:continuous \\ 
jump\:\:of\:F_X & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases}

My question is about the first inequality in $P(\{a\})=\lim_{\epsilon \to -\ 0^+}P(a- \epsilon<X\leq a)$

Does this expression hold for the continuous case? Because the limit of $(a- \epsilon)$ when $\epsilon \to \ 0^+$ is $a$.

I would express it as $P(\{a\})=\lim_{\epsilon \to -\ 0^+}P(a- \epsilon\leq X\leq a)$ though I don't know if it is right from a probabilistic point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right)\le P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right)\le P\left(a-2\epsilon< X\le a\right)\ ,
$$
it follows from the [sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement) that
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right)\ ,
$$
so the limit is the same, regardless of whether the left inequality is strict or not.  However if $\ F_X\ $ isn't continuous at $\ a-\epsilon\ $, then
$$
P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right)\ne F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)\ ,
$$
whereas the identity
$$
P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right) = F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)
$$
always holds. Thus, the identity
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\left(F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)\right)
$$
is a trivial consequence of the previous one, but
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}\left(F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)\right)\ ,
$$
while still true, isn't such a trivial consequence.  Thus, in the derivation you give, use of the *strict* inequality is far preferable to use of the non-strict one.

Comment: If I understand it correctly this interval $(a-\frac{\epsilon}{2}< X\le a)$ is smaller than $(a-\epsilon\le X\le a)$, then the probability of the first interval will be also smaller than the probability of the second interval. What I don't understand is why from $P\left(a-\frac{\epsilon}{2}< X\le a\right)\le P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right)\le $$P\left(a-2\epsilon< X \le a\right)$ 
it follows that the two limits below are equal.

Comment: The result follows from the [sandwich theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement).  Since the the two outer terms in the chain of inequalities approach the same limit as $\ \epsilon\rightarrow0^+\ $, the middle term, sandwiched between them, must also converge to the same limit.

Comment: Thanks. Two more doubts.
1) Why if $F_X$ isn't continuous at $(a- \epsilon)$, then $P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right)$ can't be equal to $F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)$

2) As I see it, the correct answer would be  $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon\leq X\le a\right)$, because $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}(a-\epsilon)$ can be equal to $a$ in the continuous case or less than $a$ in the discrete case.

Comment: As for $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right)$ then in the continuous case you would have that $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right)= P\left(a< X\le a\right)$ and then $X>a$.

Comment: Response to doubt $1$) above: By definition, \begin{align}F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)&=P(a-\epsilon<X\le a)\\&=P(a-\epsilon\le X\le a)-P(X=a-\epsilon)\ , \end{align}and when $\ F_X\ $ is not continuous at $\ a-\epsilon\ $, $\ P(X=a-\epsilon)>0\ $, so  $\ F_X(a)-F_X(a-\epsilon)< P(a-\epsilon\le X\le a)\ $.

Comment: "and when $F_X$ is not continuous at $a-\epsilon$. In this case,I think that  the only point where is not continuous is at $a$

Comment: Response to doubt $2$): I don't really understand this comment.  Since $\ \lim_\limits{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}(a-\epsilon)=a\ $, period, it *cannot* be less than $\ a\ $, regardless of whether you're considering the continuous or the non-continuous case.

Comment: Also, neither $\ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon\le X\le a\right)\ $ nor $\ \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right)\ $ is an *answer* to anything.  The latter expression is an intermediate quantity in a chain of identities.  Those identities would *still be correct*, but *less obviously so*, if it were to be replaced with the former expression.

Comment: In the continuous case, $\ \lim_\limits{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}P\left(a-\epsilon< X\le a\right)\ $, $\ P(X=a)\ $, and $\ P(a<X\le a)\ $ are all zero, and therefore equal.  I don't understand what you mean by "and then $\ X>a\ $, which is not possible".  The probability that $\ X>a\ $ is completely unrelated to any of three preceding quantities.

Comment: Why do you think that $\ a\ $ is the only point where $\ F_X\ $ might be discontinuous?  If you had been told that *explicitly* then you would know that $\ P(a-\epsilon<X\le a) = P(a-\epsilon\le X\le a)\ $ for all $\ \epsilon>0\ $, it would be completely immaterial whether you chose to use the strict or the non-strict inequality, and my comment that the strict one would make the result more obvious would not apply.  However, since the result is true *in general*, *without* that assumption, I see no reason to presume that it's true unless you *were* told so explicitly.

Comment: "Why do you think that  $a$  is the only point where  $F_X$ might be discontinuous?" Because in the OP was stated that there was a jump discontinuity when the function $F_X$ was not continuous.